# Firestore RESTful API Query only returns readTime as payload

Tags: firebase, rest, google-cloud-firestore, restful-url

I am running the following `POST`request (`GET` won't work, if anyone was trying and landed here):
URL: `https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{{ firebaseProjectID  }}/databases/(default)/documents:runQuery`

The JSON payload I send:

```
{
    "structuredQuery": {
    "from": [
      {
        "collectionId": "items"
      }
    ],
    "where": {
      "fieldFilter": {
        "field": {
          "fieldPath": "inStock"
        },
        "op": "EQUAL",
        "value": {
          "booleanValue": true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I receive the following in return:

```
[
  {
    "readTime": "2020-04-19T19:38:00.808564Z"
  }
]
```

Why do I receive not a list of documents? I certainly have matching documents.

I should receive all fields given that I entered no list of fields:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/StructuredQuery#Projection

Comment: Are you sure there aren't any security rules that prevent reading documents?

Comment: I just tried it again with `"allDescendants": true` and that worked. Weird that it didn't return any error type.

Comment: `"allDescendants": true` means that you execute a Group Collection Query. Is that the case (i.e. you have several collections with the name `items`)?

Comment: I don't, but I thought the same thing that's why I excluded it.

Comment: Hhmmm... That's strange, I use the same type of API call in several projects and it works correctly.

Comment: I made the mistake of not going to the right path in the URL, apologies.

Comment: No worries, it has happened once to all of the developers ! :-)

Comment: @Spurious Please let us know what was the change in the url? I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Posting as Community Wiki, due to the talk that occurred in the comments of the question.

As discussed in the comments, between @RenaudTarnec and @Spurious, it seems that the problem was related to the path in the URL. Once it was corrected - might be related to the `"allDescendants": true`, but it should not - the call worked and returned the values as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this will happen even if the query is perfectly valid, but there are no responsive documents in the set. No non-200 error, no empty set of results, just some random readTime in place of where the (empty) results should be... Not good.

To test you can manipulate something that will put a document into the result set and then re-run.